# Move location of drush

Tags: drush

Currently there is a .drush folder in my user profile on my mac. However, is it possible to move it into my git repo? How does one move it? If I drag and drop it, then run a drush command, the folder is remade in my user profile folder.

Comment: What are you specifically looking to move?  If it's just your Drush aliases, then they you can create a project specific `SITENAME.aliases.drushrc.php` and put it in the *sites/all/drush* folder of your Drupal install. [Source](http://drush.ws/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php)

Comment: Hi, what does this file do?

Comment: If you don't know what it does, then chances are this isn't what you wanted to move.  Check out the source though (it's linked to in the above comment), it's a really neat feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your Mac is running a version of the Unix operating system.

Files and directories starting with a dot (.) in Unix are hidden system files/directories and should not be moved or deleted unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: .drush files can be moved. and for example, there is also a .gitignore file and this contains rules that need to be modified sometimes and could easily be moved to copy config.

Comment: I am not saying that you cannot move these files, only that you should not do this *unless* you know what you're doing *and* have a specific purpose in mind.  The way your question is written suggests that this is not the case here.